# Username and password input code validation

Tags: c#

I use the login method to create an user account. When enter key is pressed without entering any character in username and password fields, it get stored in a file with a separator(:) and when trying to log in into the account without entering any character the account gets open. Which validation code should I use that it don't move to the next step until a username and password is inputted?

```
public string getPassword()
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo key;
    string pass = "";
    do
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            pass += key.KeyChar;
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                pass = pass.Remove(pass.Length - 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Password cannot be less than 0");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("Re-enter password: ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            }
        }
    } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    return pass.Remove(pass.Length - 1);
}

public void Login()
{            
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    Console.Write("\nEnter username: ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    Console.Write("Enter password: ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    password = getPassword();
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise on the question? I don't know what exactly you are asking. What do you expect your program to do and what does it do right now instead?

Comment: It's just a simple login console application. It asks for username and password. The password is hidden behind asterisk. When enter key is pressed without any input to the username it moves to the password and without any input in the password it moves to the next step. I simply want that it doesn't move to the next step until an username is inputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code i guess this is what you want

```
 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.Write("\nEnter username: ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        var username = Console.ReadLine();
        if (username != null && username.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.Write("Enter password: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            var password = getPassword();
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Main();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the string method "isNullOrEmpty" in an if statment.

```
if (!username.isNullOrEmpty)
   if (!password.isNullOrEmpty)
      // Do something
```

That will check if both username and password are filled with actual characters, not blank or spaces or tabs or whatever.